# removing one select box which is rendered with react-select module

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have 10 Select attributes which are rendered with 'react-select' module
for each select box i have different selected default value like below

select1   defaultoption1
select2   defaultoption2
select3   defaultoption3
select4   defaultoption4
select5   defaultoption5
.
.
.
select10   defaultoption10

Now i have removed the select3

Now select box default values are displaying like 
select1   defaultoption1
select2   defaultoption2
select4   defaultoption3
select5   defaultoption4
.
.
.
select10   defaultoption9

Comment: ok show your code

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, I recommend you to read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question so we can help you way more quickly.